# C++ beginner wrote Conway's game of life using SFML

Tags: c++, beginner, c++17, game-of-life, sfml

I'm an intermediate Java programmer trying to learn the basics of C++.

Thus, I decided to write "Conway's game of life" as my second C++ program (I already wrote a Mandelbrot image generator). It was a fun exercise but I struggled a lot with structuring my program and dealing with pointers and references.

It's a bit of a mishmash because I wanted to try to learn how to use both regular pointers and smart pointers, and I also implemented the `Grid` class to practice how to use templates and lambdas.

Never used SFML, never written a game. Never written a game loop so I don't really understand what I have done and all the documentation out there about game loops was difficult for me to understand.

All in all, it was a fun experience and please give me tips on structure, improvements, what was good, what was bad, should I give up and take up another hobby?

I would really like to become a better C++ developer.

[Git repository for source code](https://github.com/Tandolf/Game-Of-Life)

**main.cpp**

```
int main()
{
    Game game(2048, 1024, "Game Of Life");
    game.run();
}
```

**Game.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/System/Clock.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <time.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "LifeState.hpp"
#include "Game.hpp"

const int Game::FPS = 25;
const int Game::SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / FPS;

Game::Game(const int width, const int height, const std::string title) {
    this->data->window.create(sf::VideoMode(width, height), title);
    this->data->assets.loadTexture("tile", "assets/tile.png");
    this->data->assets.loadTexture("tile2", "assets/tile2.png");
    this->lifeState.init(this->data);
};

void Game::run(){

    int nextGameTick = clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds();
    struct timespec tim, tim2;
    tim.tv_sec = 0;
    tim.tv_nsec = 0;

    while (this->data->window.isOpen()) {
        updateGame();
        displayGame();

        nextGameTick += SKIP_TICKS;

        tim.tv_nsec = (nextGameTick - clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds());

        if(tim.tv_nsec >= 0){
            nanosleep(&tim, &tim2);
        }
    }
}

void Game::updateGame(){

    this->lifeState.update();

    sf::Event event;
    while (this->data->window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            this->data->window.close();
        }

        if(event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed) {
            auto mouse_pos = sf::Mouse::getPosition(this->data->window);
            sf::Vector2<float> translated_pos = this->data->window.mapPixelToCoords(mouse_pos);
            this->lifeState.toggle(translated_pos);

            std::cout << "mouse clicked at: " << event.mouseButton.x << " " << event.mouseButton.y << std::endl;
        }

        if(event.type == sf::Event::KeyReleased) {
            if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Space) {
                if(lifeState.isGenerating) {
                    this->lifeState.stop();
                } else {
                    this->lifeState.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void Game::displayGame(){
    this->data->window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
    this->lifeState.draw();
    this->data->window.display();
}
```

**AssetManager.cpp**

```
#include "AssetManager.hpp"

void AssetManager::loadTexture(std::string name, std::string filename) {
    sf::Texture texture;

    if(texture.loadFromFile(filename)) {
        this->textures[name] = texture;
    }
}

sf::Texture *AssetManager::getTexture(std::string name) {
    return &this->textures.at(name);
}
```

**LifeState.cpp**

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include "LifeState.hpp"
#include <SFML/System/Clock.hpp>


void LifeState::init(GameDataRef &data) {
    this->data = data;
    auto size = this->data->assets.getTexture("tile")->getSize();
    int width = this->data->window.getSize().x / size.x;
    int height = this->data->window.getSize().y / size.y;

    auto boolean = [](int x, int y, int height, int width) { return false; };

    this->currentState.fill(height, width, boolean);
    this->nextState.fill(height, width, boolean);

    int posX = 0;
    int posY = 0;
    sf::Texture* tile = this->data->assets.getTexture("tile");

    this->sprites.fill(height, width, [tile, posX, posY](int x, int y, int height, int width) mutable {
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTexture(*tile);
        sprite.setTextureRect(sf::IntRect(0, 0, tile->getSize().x, tile->getSize().y));
        sprite.setPosition(posX, posY);
        posX += tile->getSize().x;

        if(y == width-1) {
            posY += tile->getSize().y;
            posX = 0;
        }

        return sprite;
    });

    this->lastTime = 0;
};

void LifeState::toggle(sf::Vector2<float> translated_pos) {

    this->sprites.forEach([&translated_pos, this](sf::Sprite sprite, int x, int y){
        if(sprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(translated_pos)) {
            if(this->currentState.get(x, y)) {
                this->currentState.set(x, y, false);
            } else {
                this->currentState.set(x, y, true);
            }
        }
    });
}

void LifeState::draw() {

    sf::Texture* tile = this->data->assets.getTexture("tile");
    sf::Texture* tile2 = this->data->assets.getTexture("tile2");

    sprites.forEach([this, tile, tile2](sf::Sprite sprite, int x, int y){
        if(this->currentState.get(x, y)) {
            sprite.setTexture(*tile2);
        } else {
            sprite.setTexture(*tile);
        }
        this->data->window.draw(sprite);
    });
}

void LifeState::start() {
    std::cout << "Started simulation" << std::endl;
    isGenerating = true;
}

void LifeState::stop() {
    std::cout << "Stopped simulation" << std::endl;
    isGenerating = false;
}

void LifeState::update() {

    if(isGenerating) {
        double time_counter = 0;

        int thisTime = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();

        time_counter += (double)(thisTime - this->lastTime);

        if(time_counter > 0)
        {
            currentState.forEach([this](bool value, int x, int y) {
                const int neighbours = this->getNeighbours(x, y);
                this->updateCell(x, y, neighbours);
            });

            this->currentState = nextState;
        }
        this->lastTime = thisTime;
    }
}

int LifeState::getNeighbours(const int i, const int j) {
    int neighbours = 0;

    if(i == this->currentState.sizeX()-1 && j == currentState.sizeY(i)-1) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(currentState.get(i-1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(currentState.get(i, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i == this->currentState.sizeX()-1 && j > 0) {

        if(this->currentState.get(i, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i == this->currentState.sizeX()-1 && j == 0) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i == 0 && j == 0) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i == 0 && j == this->currentState.sizeY(i)-1) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i == 0 && j > 0) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i > 0 && j == 0) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i > 0 && j == this->currentState.sizeY(i)-1) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }

    if(i > 0 && j > 0) {
        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j+1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }

        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if(this->currentState.get(i+1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if(this->currentState.get(i, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        if(this->currentState.get(i-1, j-1)) {
            neighbours++;
        }
        return neighbours;
    }
    return neighbours;
}

void LifeState::updateCell(const int height, const int width, const int neighbours) {

    const bool isActive = this->currentState.get(height, width);

    if(neighbours < 2 && isActive) {
        this->nextState.set(height, width, false);
        return;
    } else if((neighbours == 2 || neighbours == 3) && isActive) {
        this->nextState.set(height, width, true);
        return;
    } else if(neighbours > 3 && isActive) {
       this->nextState.set(height, width, false);
        return;
    } else if(isActive == false && neighbours == 3) {
        this->nextState.set(height, width, true);
        return;
    }
}
```

**Grid.hpp**

```
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Grid {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<T>> data;

public:
    void fill(int x, int y, const std::function<T(int, int, int, int)> &func);
    std::size_t sizeX();
    std::size_t sizeY(int x);
    void forEach(const std::function<void(T, int, int)> &func);
    T get(int x, int y);
    void set(int x, int y, T value);
};

template<typename T>
void Grid<T>::fill(int x, int y, const std::function<T(int, int, int, int)> &func) {
    data.reserve(x);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        std::vector<T> v;
        v.reserve(y);
        data.push_back(v);
        std::cout << y << std::endl;
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            T value = func(i, j, data.size(), y);
            this->data.at(i).push_back(value);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
std::size_t Grid<T>::sizeX() {
    return data.size();
}

template<typename T>
std::size_t Grid<T>::sizeY(int x) {
    return data.at(x).size();
}

template<typename T>
void Grid<T>::forEach(const std::function<void(T, int, int)> &func) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < data.at(i).size(); j++) {
            func(data.at(i).at(j), i, j);
        }
    }
}

template<typename T>
T Grid<T>::get(int x, int y) {
    return data.at(x).at(y);
}

template<typename T>
void Grid<T>::set(int x, int y, T value) {
    data.at(x).at(y) = value;
}
```

I have omitted some of the header files, but you can find them all in the source code repository.

Comment: oh wow didn't even notice that, i have changed it to `include`.

Comment: Take a look at [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/388242) on Stack Overflow.

Comment: thank you for the book tips! much appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to C++!  Java and C++ are quite different languages with different programming idioms and techniques, so hopefully this review will help you get better in C++.

## `main.cpp`

The first thing I noticed is that you omitted the `#include` when posting your `main.cpp` code.  I checked your GitHub repository and noticed that `#include "Game.hpp"` is present in the `main.cpp` file.  Please post complete code in the future.

When I see the line

```
Game game(2048, 1024, "Game Of Life");
```

I wonder which of the two numbers is the width and which is the height (if they are supposed to be dimensions at all) and what the `"Game Of Life"` string means.  You didn't post your `Game.hpp` file, but I go ahead and check it.  There is a constructor:

```
Game(const int width, const int height, const std::string title);
```

which answers the questions.  It would be better if a reader does not need to examine another file to understand the code.  In this case, a simple comment is sufficient:

```
// creates a 2048 x 1024 game with title "Game Of Life"
Game game(2048, 1024, "Game Of Life");
```

This approach has drawbacks: the comment is invalidated when the code changes, and comments shouldn't be used to indicate how the code works.  For more complicated cases, the [named argument idiom](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#named-parameter-idiom) is commonly used.

## `Game.cpp`

You didn't actually post `Game.hpp`.  I can check your code on GitHub, but this answer can only review `Game.cpp`.

You included `<time.h>`.  C headers of the form `<time.h>` are deprecated in favor of `<ctime>`.  In fact, you should be using `<chrono>` instead of `<ctime>` in C++.

```
const int Game::FPS = 25;
const int Game::SKIP_TICKS = 1000 / FPS;
```

These two lines are (probably) definitions of static `const` variables.  They can be made `constexpr` and defined directly in-class.  `ALL_CAPS` identifiers are usually reserved for macros, and constants shouldn't really use them.  In C++, types are used to assign values meanings.  Make a type alias `fps_t` for the type of `fps`:

```
using fps_t = int;
```

Also, `skip_ticks` seems to be a time duration instead of a pure integer, so use `chrono`:

```
// in the Game class declaration
static constexpr fps_t fps = 25;
static constexpr auto skip_ticks = 1000ms / fps;
```

(Assumes `using namespace std::chrono_literals`.)  `1000ms` is unambiguously 1000 milliseconds instead of 1000 microseconds or 1000 Minecraft ticks.

`this->` has limited use and is redundant in your case, so leave them out.  This applies to all functions.

Your constructor declares all parameters as `const`.  This is not necessary.  Also, `title` should be passed by `std::string_view`.

The `run` function is where the C time facilities become a bit unhandy with `timespec` and pointers.  Here's what the same code looks like when written using C++ chrono facilities: (just an idea, not tested because I am not familiar with SFML clocks)

```
void Game::run()
{
    std::chrono::milliseconds nextGameTick{clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()};
    while (data->window.isOpen()) {
        updateGame();
        displayGame();

        nextGameTick += skip_ticks;                               // the units are handled properly by the type system

        std::chrono::milliseconds current_time{clock.getElapsedTime().asMilliseconds()};
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(nextGameTick - current_time); // more intuitive than timespec and nanosleep
    }
}
```

This needs `#include <chrono>` and `#include <thread>` (for [`sleep_until`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_until)).

The `updateGame` function uses a bunch of `if`s.  At least they should be made `else if` to avoid redundant checking.  And the right tool here is `switch`:

```
switch (event.type) {
case sf::Event::Closed:
    // ...
    break;
case sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed:
    // ...
    break;
case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
    // ...
    break;
}
```

Your use of `endl` is justified because flushing is required here.  This may deserve a comment.

## `AssetManager.cpp`

Both functions should pass the strings by `string_view` instead of `string` by value.  And it may be more convenient for `getTexture` to return a reference instead of a pointer.

## `LifeState.cpp`

Several of your lambdas can be simplified with default captures.  For example, `[=]` instead of `[tile, posX, posY]`, and `[&]` instead of `[&translated_pos, this]`.  The lambda in `draw` can also be `[&]` if you make `getTexture` return a reference as recommended above, or make `tile` and `tile2` references.

The process of assigning the game data should probably be in the constructor of the `LifeState` class instead of the `init` function.  Don't name the parameter identically to the data member.  `boolean` is not a useful name for the lambda.  `always_false` is better.

The `update` function can similarly be rewritten using `chrono`.

In the `getNeighbours` function, use prefix `++` instead of postfix `++`.  Replace all `neighbours++` with `++neighbours`.  And the logic should probably be simplified or organized somehow ...

## `Grid.hpp`

Generic templates are not easy to get right.  You definitely shouldn't be implementing `Grid` yourself in this project.  Use an existing library instead.

A `vector<vector<T>>` doesn't feel good.  A library should use contiguous memory internally.

You are using `.at` all over the place.  Use `[]` when you have control over the index to reduce performance penalty.

`fill` should be a constructor, and should accept any callable object.  `std::function` shouldn't be used here at all.  And in this case, the use of `std::endl` is inherently wrong — you don't need to flush every single time and `'\n'` is the way to go.  `int` also doesn't feel right here.  And your implementation is needlessly complex.  Here's a basic proofread (not tested):

```
template <typename T, typename F>
Grid<T>::Grid(size_type x, size_type y, F f)
    :data(x)
{
    for (size_type i = 0; i < x; ++i) {
        data[i].reserve(y);
        std::cout << y << '\n';
        for (size_type j = 0; j < y; ++j) {
            data[i].push_back(f(i, j, i + 1, y)); // the arguments are guessed
        }
    }
}
```

where `size_type` is declared beforehand with

```
using size_type = typename decltype(data)::size_type;
```

I don't see how `sizeY` should be taking an argument.  The grid is supposed to be rectangular, right?

The `get` and `set` functions also feel a bit anti-C++-ish.  `get` should be made `const`.  I'd expect this in C++:

```
template <typename T>
T& Grid<T>::operator()(size_type x, size_type y)
{
    return data.at(x).at(y);
}

template <typename T>
const T& Grid<T>::operator()(size_type x, size_type y) const
{
    return data.at(x).at(y);
}
```

This way, we can do `grid(x, y)` to get and `grid(x, y) = value` to set.

Again, there are too many ways in which this feels unidiomatic and *please use an existing library instead of rolling out your own.*

Comment: this is excellent, thank you for all your comments!

Comment: I **strongly** disagree that a comment improves the constructor call. In fact, it makes it *worse* because it gives the reader false confidence. In reality, the comment could be completely wrong (e.g. width & height switched) and the reader would be none the wiser. This comment is a typical, extreme anti-pattern: It’s the cause of numerous hard to find bugs. Unfortunately there are no good and simple solutions to this issue. The best is to use strong typing with a named-argument idiom, and write `auto game = Game{width{2048}, height{1024}, title{"foobar"}};`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I also prefer the named argument approach.  In this case, the constructors are not gonna be reused anyway, and since OP is relatively new to C++, that may be too much for him I guess.  I'll update my answer to incorporate this information.

Comment: i looked into the "named-argument idiom" and that is what we call the "builder-pattern" in Java! nice to see that this pattern is also used in C++

Comment: @ThomasAndolf Just to be clear, there are multiple completely different implementations of that idiom, and the one I was referring to isn’t the builder pattern (I’d call that builder pattern in C++!) and I strongly recommend *against* using it. I’d call that an anti-pattern in C++ because it makes it impossible to have `const` objects. In C++, an object should be be fully initialised once the constructor has finished running. The same is true in Java — builders should always generate a *different type*, such as `StringBuilder`, which is used to build an immutable `String`. This usage is OK.

Comment: @KonradRudolph ah yes, thank you for pointing that out, i actually noticed that yesterday when i was coding that in the example `OpenFile` returns a `File` So its more of a sort of factory pattern-isch. I fully agree with you in everything you say. Oh i have sooooooo many questions about C++ i find it very fascinating, it's like a mix of both new and old. I really appreciate you taking the time helping me, really.